# "Aaron is a genius boy"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, idioms

I wonder whether can we call someone a *genius boy*? I've been using this term to describe my cousin until someone told me that the correct usage should be *boy genius*.

The question is: Can we say *Aaron is a genius boy*? Is it *wrong*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both are technically correct, but the idiomatic usage is "boy genius".

Comment: It emphasizes the trait of genius being seen in the boy at an early age.

Comment: Like "Valentina Tereshkova was the first woman astronaut."

Answer (score 12):

"Genius Boy" sounds sarcastic to me:  "Everything was going great until Genius Boy here turned out the lights."

Comment: It didn't sound sarcastic to me till I read this answer, and now it does.

Comment: *Boy genius* can also be meant sarcastically, but someone described as *genius boy* is almost certainly a bit of a dunce.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that the word "genius" in this context is being used as an adjective, which it is not - the adjective form is "ingenious". "Boy genius" is idiomatically preferable, as indicated elsewhere.

Comment: Yet another bizarre, wrongheaded answer not only upvoted but accepted - "boy" is a noun as is "genius".

Comment: He says that "genius" is not an adjective and that "boy genius" is "idiomatically preferable," not that it's necessarily correct.

Comment: I don't see much wrong with this answer. It is fine, as are several others.

Answer (score 3):

You can say *genius boy* in the same way you say, for example, *ninja boy* (*ninja* is a noun that modifies a noun); the correct expression you are asking for is *boy genius*, though.

Comment: Do you mean "cast iron"? Either way, "cast" here is being used as an adjective, being the (irregular) past participle of the verb "to cast".

Comment: @Steve: Whoops; I was sure it was _iron cast_. I should find a case of `<noun as adjective> <noun>`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you mean "boy genius" unless you are trying to create your own term.

I've never heard "genius boy", and "boy genius" is a standard term for "whiz kid":
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_genius

Comment: But what about "he is a genius boy"? Is it wrong?

Comment: No, it's not wrong. It's obvious what you mean. It's just a new term.

Comment: New term! Ah, I don't want to reinvent new terms. I'll just stick to boy genius then

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think of it being a formal term, but perfectly usable.  The emphasis changes depending on the word order.  "Boy genius" is talking about a genius who is a boy.  "Genius boy" is talking about a boy who is a genius.

Answer (score -2):

"Genius" and "boy" are both nouns. **(Note that the adjective "ingenious" in present English usage is not at all related to the word "genius".)** Take some examples:

> Genius scientist

is wrong.

Instead we prefer

> scientific genius

However, both

> boy wonder

and

> wonder boy

are acceptable, so it seems that "boy" can be used either as a noun modifier (noun-as-adjective) or as a noun.

I don't know if this generalizes to other words in similar categories or not, but I am 100% sure that the accepted and upvoted answer is wrong and thoroughly misguided.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with your answer that I can see, but once again you point out that lotsoffreetime's answer is wrong. You don't mention why, though, which seems a touch discourteous, in addition to ineffective. Would you mind explaining, please?

Comment: This answer is wrong, pure and simple. _Genius_ is both a noun and an adjective (“That’s an absolutely genius idea!” works fine), while _boy_ is only a noun (“What a completely boy thing to do” does not work at all). There’s nothing ‘wrong’ about _genius scientist_ or _genius boy_; it’s just that _boy genius_ and _boy wonder_ (both using _boy_ as a noun adjunct) are idiomatic expressions, while _genius boy_ and _wonder boy_ are not.